# C++ Read words and lines in same reading loop

Tags: c++, search, getline

I've understood how to look for and read words from a text file. I also understand how you can use getline() to go trough a text and read a certain line.

But now I'm trying to figure out how to use both in the same "reading loop".

It would be something like this:

```
    string S1="mysearchword01",S2="mysearchword02";
    char word[50];

    while(myfile.good()){  //while didn't reach the end line

         file>>word; //go to next word
         if (word==S1){ //if i find S1 I cout the two next words
             file>>a>>b;
             cout<<a<<" "<<b<<endl;}
             }
         else if (word==S2) {
            //****here I want to cout or save the full line*****    
             }
    }
```

So can I use getline in there somehow?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `while(myfile.good())` This is wrong. It will return true on an empty file. To read a line, use `string line; while (getline(myfile, line)) {..}`

Comment: while(myfile.good()) is working for me. If I use that code without the "else if" it looks trough my text file word by word for S1. If it finds it calls out the two next words. Then the while loop stops when it hits the end of the file.

Comment: word is supposed to be a char, not string, will edit.

Comment: Why not just use `std::string` as you did?

Comment: @PeterGoldsborough Yes, it would probably work also. I just noticed that in my original code I was using char. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::fstream::good()` checks whether the last I/O operation was successful, and, while it works in the way you implement it, it is not really what you want here.

Use `getline(file, stringToStoreInto)` in place of the call to `good()` in the while loop, it will also return false when the end of the file has been reached.

EDIT: To extract single whitespace-delimited elements (words) from the line you get from `std::getline()`, you can use an `std::stringstream`, initialize it with the line string, and then extract single words out of that stringstream into another "word" string using the `>>` operator.

So for your case, something like this would do:

```
#include <sstream>

std::string line, word;

while (getline(file, line))
{
    std::stringstream ss(line);

    ss >> word;

    if (word == S1)
    {
        // You can extract more from the same stringstream
        ss >> a >> b;
    }

    else if (word == S2)
    {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can also instantiate the stringstream object once and call its `str()` method, one overload of which resets the stream while the other overload replaces its content.

```
#include <sstream>

std::stringstream ss;

std::string line, word;

while (getline(file, line))
{
    ss.str(line); // insert / replace contents of stream

    ss >> word;

    if (word == S1)
    {
        // You can extract more from the same stringstream
        ss >> a >> b;
    }

    else if (word == S2)
    {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

You can use the stringstream to extract multiple words, not just the first, just keep calling `operator>>` like you did before.

Comment: Ok, thank you. But in this case, word will be the whole line? Not the first word in the line?

Comment: @remi000 word will be the whole line here. If you put it in a stringstream, you can then extract the actual words.

Comment: Yes, that is the purpose of getline. If you want whitespace-delimited elements from that line you can either follow Neil's advice or write some splitting function like Python's `split()` method for built-in strings.

Comment: Alright. So basically, I would have to check line by line with stringstream to see if the first word is my searching word. If it is, I can use stringstream again to extract whatever words I want in that line. Or if I want the full line, word would be that line?

Comment: Yes you can extract more words, see my new edits to the answer.